# Reading a non-uniform file into a single array in python

Tags: python, numpy, file, readlines

I am trying to read a single non csv file into a single array in python. I have tried np.loadtxt, however the data has columns of different widths and even skipping those, loadtxt returns arrays of line values that cannot be appended together.
[image: The data file in question]

Comment: Can you share this file please?

Comment: Sure thing! http://www.filedropper.com/fort

Comment: There is 18050 values. The dimension is 50x360 (=18000). So it remains 50 values (the first dim). How to interpret your array?

Comment: I'd like the array to be every row, one after the other. The file is an outpit from a program that lists reaults in a certain order. My plan is to write a function to append them once they're all in one array

Comment: looks like there are 2 blocks, that will require separate reads  - and separate arrays.

Comment: That would be fine too, I think. So maybe using readlines for the two blocks separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple read should be sufficient for now:

```
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    next(fp)  # skip first line (length)
    m = np.array(fp.read().strip().split()).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
>>> m
array([1.001000e-06, 1.545000e-06, 2.399000e-06, ..., 9.999984e-01,
       9.999984e-01, 1.000000e+00])

>>> m.dtype
dtype('float64')

>>> m.shape
(18050,)
```

Note the first line indicates 50 and 350. The length of the array is **18050**.
This is the sum of **50 + 50 x 350**. How to interpret this lines?